# BlueStacks uses lots of Internet traffic

Tags: windows-7, bluestacks

I installed BlueStacks on Windows 7 Home Premium. It's using lots of Internet traffic. I've noticed that even when I'm not using BlueStacks, it's in system tray, fetching data and slowing down my Internet browsing.

I'm only using WhatsApp, which only uses a few bytes for texting, but more than 50 MB have been consumed by BlueStacks.

Where does the traffic come from? How can I stop it?

Comment: 50 MB isn't a lot. Even WhatsApp transmits more than just a few bytes. Rather in the range of MB if you take into account push notifications and polling.

Answer (score 1):

BlueStacks may be performing self-upgrades in background.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that BlueStacks uses its native service named **com.bluestacks.gomepophome** which can not be stoped easily.

If you stopped it anyway, it would restart when you go to home screen.

This service is used to download various games from configured providers (having  `.cfg` files in the BlueStacks folder).